# Math applied to a real world project.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

so this is about an electronics project, but you don't need to know electronics to answer it.

I have a weighing scale that I'm building with a load sensor. When I calibrate the unit. I first check the zero weight.

First Weight 43.4 = 1071 (raw sensor value)

then I weigh a 500 gram weight.

Max 500 Grams = 7443 (raw sensor value)

Once the calibration is done I read signals from the load sensor (L).

$\frac{L - 1071}{7443 - 1071} \cdot543.4$

So for example:

$L = 1083$

$\frac{12}{6372} \cdot 543.4 = 1.02$

$\frac{24}{6372} \cdot 543.4 = 2.04$

$\frac{36}{6372} \cdot 543.4 = 3.07$

**Question 1.**

Because the load sensor doesn't read decimals only full numbers it starts to creep over time. Can anyone suggest a way I can handle this?

**Question 2.**

I don't know if this is possible, but sometimes when I turn on the scale the range
from 1071 to 7443 has changed slightly. For example:

Day 1: 1071 to 7443

Day 2: 1069 to 7448

Day 3: 1072 to 7445

If anyone knows of a way to calculate this in, that would be great. But i'm not sure if it's possible.

Thanks, Guys!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking, are you writing a code? Or are you simply calibrating the scale using a built in feature? What type of load sensor are you using?

Comment: Yes, i am writing code. I'm doing it on the Arduino platform. But I thought I would talk less about coding and more about the Math because I presume a lot of people here do not know programming.

Comment: I think this would be better suited in an arduino forum. Try here http://forum.arduino.cc/